# mysql query not working with where in condition

Tags: mysql

I am running following query in mysql.

```
SELECT jobtype_has_trade.jobtype_id,users_jobtype.user_id 
FROM users 
    LEFT JOIN subcontractor ON users.subcontractor_id = subcontractor.id 
        AND subcontractor.quotations = "YES" 
    LEFT JOIN users_jobtype ON users.id = users_jobtype.user_id 
        AND users_jobtype.status = "A" 
    LEFT JOIN jobtype_has_trade ON users_jobtype.jobtype_trade_id = jobtype_has_trade.id 
WHERE users.is_subcontractor = "YES" 
AND users.has_android = "YES" 
AND jobtype_has_trade.jobtype_id IN (1,3,4) 
ORDER by users_jobtype.user_id ASC
```

and i am getting this output

[image]

In above records i need only that user_id that have jobtype_id 1,3 and 4. so, user_id 3 and 7 is acceptable and 9 is not because it has only 3 and 4 as jobtype_id... in sort how can i get only 3 and 7 as user_id in above query?

Comment: On a question like this you really should show at least an example of the 4 tables you are processing and a schema for those tables would also be nice. See [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) And a SQLFiddle would achieve this very nicely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option could be to use `having clause` with `group by`

```
SELECT users_jobtype.user_id 
FROM users 
    LEFT JOIN subcontractor ON users.subcontractor_id = subcontractor.id 
        AND subcontractor.quotations = "YES" 
    LEFT JOIN users_jobtype ON users.id = users_jobtype.user_id 
        AND users_jobtype.status = "A" 
    LEFT JOIN jobtype_has_trade ON users_jobtype.jobtype_trade_id = jobtype_has_trade.id 
WHERE users.is_subcontractor = "YES" 
AND users.has_android = "YES" 
AND jobtype_has_trade.jobtype_id IN (1,3,4)
group by users_jobtype.user_id
having count(distinct jobtype_has_trade.jobtype_id)=3
```

Answer (score 1):

just check existing of jobtype_id in 1,3,4 for each user. I don't know about your schema
if you have jobtype_id in users_jobtype then you don't need to join to jobtype_has_trade in subquery in where (in my solution)

```
SELECT jobtype_has_trade.jobtype_id,
           users_jobtype.user_id
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN subcontractor ON users.subcontractor_id = subcontractor.id
    AND subcontractor.quotations = "YES"
    LEFT JOIN users_jobtype ON users.id = users_jobtype.user_id
    AND users_jobtype.status = "A"
    LEFT JOIN jobtype_has_trade ON users_jobtype.jobtype_trade_id = jobtype_has_trade.id
    WHERE users.is_subcontractor = "YES"
      AND users.has_android = "YES"
      AND jobtype_has_trade.jobtype_id IN (1,
                                           3,
                                           4)

       and exists( select jobtype_id from jobtype_has_trade inner join users_jobtype on users_jobtype.jobtype_trade_id=jobtype_has_trade.id where users_jobtype.user_id=users.id and 

        jobtype_has_trade.jobtype_id=1
       ) 
       and exists( select jobtype_id from jobtype_has_trade inner join users_jobtype on users_jobtype.jobtype_trade_id=jobtype_has_trade.id where users_jobtype.user_id=users.id and 

        jobtype_has_trade.jobtype_id=3
       )
       and exists( select jobtype_id from jobtype_has_trade inner join users_jobtype on users_jobtype.jobtype_trade_id=jobtype_has_trade.id where users_jobtype.user_id=users.id and 

        jobtype_has_trade.jobtype_id=4
       )

    ORDER BY users_jobtype.user_id ASC
```